# Determine 3D coordinates of 2D ellipse from two 2D ellipses without point correspondence

Tags: opencv, math, computer-vision, geometry, linear-algebra

**Summary**

I have two cameras at different, known poses relative to each other.

I'm using them to take a picture of a single elliptical object.

I want to use the 2D information from each image to determine the 3D pose of the ellipse, but without using point matching.

**Details**

I can easily determine the ellipse parameters that fit the image of the ellipse from each photo.

However, let's assume that it's not possible to accurately detect corresponding points between the two ellipses (e.g. we can't use SIFT/SURF matching, etc...).  So we likely can't use PNP.

So if we can only rely on

a.) the 2D ellipse parameters from each image, and

b.) the camera poses,

*is there a way to determine the 3D pose or coordinates of the ellipse?*

**Example**

Let's say this is the image of the ellipse from camera 1.

It has these parameters in the image: {"cx":264,"cy":158,"rx":18,"ry":4.243,"theta":-0.785}
[image]

And this is the image of the ellipse from camera 2.

It has these parameters in the image: {"cx":376,"cy":131,"rx":20,"ry":17,"theta":3.024}

[image]

And the "real-life ellipse" (front-on view of the ellipse) looks like this.

It has these parameters in real-life (somewhat arbitrary, aka not an actual calculation): {"cx":3,"cy":5, "cz":1,"rx":18,"ry":30,"rz":0}

[image]

I'd really like to find a way to get the parameters of the real-life ellipse from the pair of parameters from the images.  I just have no idea how that's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you assume real-life ellipse's parameters and location and pose, you can simulate captured image of the assumed ellipse for each camera (with known intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of cameras).

So, you'll be able to evaluate the assumed parameter set based on difference between the taken picture and the simulated image.

Therefore, you'll be able to search the real-life ellipse's parameter value by minimizing the error(differnece).

Comment: that, a few iterations of optimization, is pretty much what everyone does in this situation (when you only have contours, not points). fair answer, if a bit bare. -- if you look up "iterative closest point", the associate-optimize loop is showing the idea, if not the exact same steps. -- some "jacobian" matrices might be involved to drive the optimizer.

Comment: If the Objective Function becomes to hard or not able to calculate Hessian or Jacobian, optimizer such as "nelder-mead simplex" may be able to employed, I think.